# Dynamically assign feature properties on L.marker popup interactions

Tags: leaflet, popup, markers

I have a Leaflet based map on which a user can click to create a marker. Then, if one clicks on the marker a popup is opening, where one can change text in a textarea, activate the camera of the mobile device and save all markers with feature properties into a geoJSON.

I initialize an empty `L.featureGroup()`, generate dynamic HTML popupContent inside an `addMarker(e){}` function and add all this data to an object, that is being created via `.toGeoJSON()`, where I can access `feature.properties`. Because it is overwritten each time, I have to write all properties into another array `infoTextArray`

Is there a efficent way to directly write a feature's properties on creation?

**edit**: to further specify my question:

I want to assign my geoJSON features properties when they're created. I tried something like:

```
let layerGroup = L.geoJSON([], {
pointToLayer: function (feature) {
    feature.properties.infoText='';
    feature.properties.imageURL='';
},
onEachFeature: function (feature) {
    feature.properties.infoText='';
    feature.properties.imageURL=''; 
}
}).addTo(map);
```

`layerGroup.toGEOJSON()` still returns an empty feature properties object. I'm guessing my functions aren't triggered, when a new features is added to the layer.

Comment: hm...while *Leaflet* sure is an everyday tool of Web GIS developers, pure code reviews are probably better suited on the dedicated SE or even SO. might want to flag to migrate, since I'm pretty sure this will get closed as off-topic here...

Comment: okay, the code review isn't actually intented, I'm looking for a specific way to immediately access a feature property on creation

Comment: Here is an example of where I add points to a map and write them to a database. I use a div instead of the popup. I have a PHP page that takes the points and creates GeoJSON from the database. http://gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/phpDemo/adddelmod2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet's `toGeoJSON()` functionality works by using the `.feature` property of `L.Layer`s (in your case, `L.Marker`s) inside the `L.GeoJSON` group. Relevant code is [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/3bc00660f4e61e1c297c9dacc607c0740818a99c/src/layer/GeoJSON.js#L291) and  [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/3bc00660f4e61e1c297c9dacc607c0740818a99c/src/layer/GeoJSON.js#L272).

Therefore, you should **populate a `.feature` property** in your `L.Marker`s **when the markers are created** and not sooner.

e.g.:

```
var layerGroup = L.geoJSON();

map.on('click', function(ev){
  var newMarker = L.marker(ev.latlng);
  newmarker.feature = { 
    type: 'Point', 
    properties: { infoText: '', imageURL: '' }, 
    geometry: undefined 
  };
  newMarker.addTo(layerGroup);
});

// ...later
layerGroup.toGeoJSON();
```

Right now, you're trying to populate such a property of the markers *before the markers even exist*. Your `pointToLayer` and `onEachFeature` are not running ever, because they run over each feature in the GeoJSON data when the `L.GeoJSON` is instantiated, but you're instantiating it with no data - therefore each of them runs a grand total of zero times.

Comment: awesome! exactly this .feature property is what i've been looking for!

Comment: When in doubt, read Leaflet's source code. I find it's kinda easy to understand the internals, if you spend a little time.

Comment: let layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);let marker = L.marker(e.latlng,{icon:redMarkerIcon});
    marker.feature = {
        type: 'Point',
        properties: {infoText:'',imageURL:''},
        geometry:undefined
    };
    marker.bindPopup(staticPopupContent).addTo(layerGroup);

the output:JSON.stringify(layerGroup.toGeoJSON()) gives me an invalid geojson. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: output of above: 
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","properties":{"infoText":"1","imageURL":""},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[10.239257812500002,48.019324184801185]}}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","properties":{"infoText":"","imageURL":""},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[24.521484375000004,45.85941212790755]}}}]}